# How to add checkbox before submit button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to append my form, but adding a checkbox, but I want to add it before the submit button.

```
$('#form').append('<input type="checkbox" id="checking" name="checking" class="required" />').before($('.clickSubmit'));
```

`.clickSubmit` is:

```
<p class="clickSubmit"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Click to submit" class="btn btn-default" disabled="disabled"></p>
```

The code above moves the `.clickSubmit` outside my form and puts it before the form when I want the submit button in the form, I just want to add a checkbox before it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the correct syntax:

```
$('.clickSubmit').prepend('<input type="checkbox" id="checking" name="checking" class="required" />');
```

[http://api.jquery.com/prepend/](http://api.jquery.com/prepend)

The use of `before` will add it *before* the element you call it on. `Prepend` will add it as the first element under the selected element

Comment: This will place the checkbox inside the `.clickSubmit` element, yet the OP wants it outside that.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That is how i read it first, but i don't think so. Try read his question again?

Comment: Hmm. Good point. It reads as though he wants the button inside, yet the use of before with that selector implies outside.

Comment: this does not make it part of the form.

Comment: @user979331 Where is the form?

Answer (score 2):

Supposing you want the structure to look like this

```
<p class="clickSubmit">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checking" name="checking" class="required" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Click to submit" class="btn btn-default" disabled="disabled">
</p>
```

You can do

```
$('<input type="checkbox" id="checking" name="checking" class="required" />')
.insertBefore('#submit');
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because `append()` is returning the `form` element, so you're moving the entire `form` to before the button. Instead, use `insertBefore` on the new checkbox. Try this:

```
$('<input type="checkbox" id="checking" name="checking" class="required" />').insertBefore('.clickSubmit');
```